# mdadm volume works, but won't assemble/mount on startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mdadm, lvm2

I have an mdadm/lvm2 volume with 4 HDs that I created in Ubuntu 10.04. I just upgraded the computer to Ubuntu 10.10.

I redid the mdadm commands to get volume up and running, did mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf to get the configuration file.

But now, every time I reboot, it tells me that the volume is not ready. /proc/mdstat says that I always have one disk of the volume "inactive" as md_d127. I need to stop this volume and reassemble the whole thing to get it working.

This is what I get out of mdadm --detail --scan and put inside /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:

```
ARRAY /dev/md127 level=raid5 num-devices=4 metadata=01.02 name=:r0 UUID=7610a895:a54fe65b:c9876d2a:67f4a179
```

And this is my /proc/mdstat on boot:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive sdb1[2](S) sdd1[0](S) sda1[4](S)
      2930279595 blocks super 1.2

md_d127 : inactive sdc1[1](S)
      976759865 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

I need to do mdadm -S /dev/md_d127, mdadm -S /dev/md127, mdadm -A --scan to get this volume working again.

What's going on? This did not happen with Ubuntu 10.04. I'm really fearing the loss of my raid5 data now.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the updated version of `mdadm` relies on the `mdadm.conf` present in your `initrd`, which is probably not accurate/complete. To verify its contents, do this:

```
gunzip -c /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic | cpio -i --quiet --to-stdout etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

If it doesn't contain accurate ARRAY entries, mdadm will try to use the name configured in the superblock as the link name under `/dev/md/`, which will link to something like `/dev/md127`. This obviously does not match the earlier behavior.

Rather than directly using `mdadm -Ds` or `mdadm -Es` to generate `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, it's probably better to use the `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` script:

```
sudo /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf force-generate /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

The most important step is to rebuild your initramfs to include the updated configuration:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Actually, thanks to the magic in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mdadm`, `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` will be run automatically if `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` does not exist or contains no arrays. If it exists and contains only a subset of your active arrays, a warning is displayed for each missing array, and you should manually generate a new `mdadm.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

You may also check that udev is loading mdadm.

Look for `/lib/udev/rules.d/85-mdadm.rules`; make sure that it has something like this:

```
\# This file causes block devices with Linux RAID (mdadm) signatures to
\# automatically cause mdadm to be run.
\# See udev(8) for syntax

SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="linux_raid*", \
        RUN+="/sbin/mdadm --incremental $env{DEVNAME}"
```

If not copy this into `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-mdadm.rules` - NOTE `/etc` NOT `/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I've resorted to reformatting the entire array. This works in Ubuntu 10.10.

```
sudo mdadm -C /dev/md0 -l 5 -n 4 -e 1.2 /dev/sd[bcde]1
sudo mdadm -Ds | sudo tee /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

sudo pvcreate /dev/md0
sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/md0
sudo lvcreate vg0 --name lv0 --extents '100%FREE'

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/lv0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please edit this

```
metadata=01.02
```

with

```
metadata=1.02
```

Because results from

```
#mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

isn't completely correct.